# How to connect a TCP socket using a host name on a local network

Tags: xcode, objective-c++, tcpclient

I am trying to connect to a TCP socket on a Windows XP machine using the computer name from an iPad.

I've tried using:

```
getaddrinfo(hostName, 4097, &hints, &res0);
```

This fails when `hostName = "MyHost"` and succeeds when `hostName = "192.168.0.4"`

I've tried using AsynchSockets with the same results using:

```
[mySocket connectToHost:hostName onPort:4097 error:nil];
```

The XP machines do just fine connecting using:
`Winsock.RemoteHost = "MyHost"` for VB
and
`MySocket->Connect("MyHost", 4097);` for C++

How do I do something similar on the iPad using Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need an SMB client library for iOS.  Here's a place to start:

http://38leinad.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/windows-filesharing-library-for-ios/

Comment: I downloaded the Tango SMB client library for iOS and found the function address_for_host().  It uses the deprecated function gethostbyname().\n  When I called it with "10.0.0.4" it returned 0x4000000a and when I called it with "MyHost" it returned INADDR_NONE (0xffffffff)  Any other suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it works with direct IP and doesn't with a hostName 'MyHost'
this most probably means that 'MyHost' isn't getting resolved (to an IP) on iPad.
For example: there's a file called hosts (usually `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)
on an XP machine - where a host name like MyHost can have it's IP defined.

A line "`192.168.0.4 MyHos`t" would do just that.

It seems you can't edit hosts file on non-jailbroken iPad: [Can I edit an iPad's host file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783923/can-i-edit-an-ipads-host-file)

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917107/how-can-i-redirect-http-requests-made-from-an-ipad) you can find a way around this.